# Chrome set system wide proxy

Tags: proxy

when I set up a socket proxy in chrome and click the "apply system wide" button. does that mean that every software that connects to the internet is going to use that proxy, including chats and others?
Kind Regards

Comment: You can use a command line option to have chrome use a proxy without changing the system settings.  For example I have my launcher set to execute this command `/usr/bin/chromium-browser --proxy-bypass-list="localhost,127.0.0.1" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080"` Obviously change chromium for chrome and if you aren't using a socks5 proxy change that protocol as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is. Chrome actually open network-proxy (which is default install in ubuntu).